# How to access a private repo in YAML (repos.yaml) in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, yaml, devops, repo

I'm trying to access a private GitHub repository using a YAML configuration file (e.g., repos.yaml). How can I securely integrate authentication from GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a private GitHub repository within your YAML configuration or any other configuration where you might need to specify the repository URL, you can incorporate your GitHub username and personal access token (PAT) directly into the URL. Here's the format:

```
https://github_username:personal_access_token@github.com/project_name/repo.git
```

`github_username`: Replace this with your GitHub username.

`personal_access_token`: Replace this with the PAT you've generated from your GitHub settings. This token acts as a password, granting the necessary permissions to access your private repository.

`project_name`: This refers to the owner of the repository which could be an individual user or an organization.

`repo.git`: Replace this with the name of your repository, ending with .git.

Important Considerations:

- Security: This approach embeds sensitive information (your PAT) into
  URLs, which might be logged or exposed in certain scenarios. Always
  be cautious about where and how you use this method. If you're using
  this URL in scripts or configuration files, ensure those files are
  secure and not exposed publicly.
- Token Permissions: When creating a PAT in GitHub, you can assign
  specific permissions to it. Ensure your token has the required
  permissions for the actions you intend to perform using the
  repository URL.

Remember, the PAT is like a password, so treat it with the same level of confidentiality.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question, and you left out a lot of useful detail (such as answers to "which operating system?" and "what exactly are you trying to do?" and "what are the constraints you're trying to work within?"), but there is another answer: SSH.

If the process retrieving repos has access to a private key, perhaps through an `~/.ssh/config` or `ssh-agent`, and if the matching public key is either a) attached to an account with appropriate permissions or b) set up as a deploy key, then the URL format `git@github.com:owner/repo` should work.

Comment: Yes, I answered since it wasn't available on SO. Now someone can make use of it BTW thanks for adding the info.